# QTextCursor and beginEditBlock

Tags: qt, qt5, qplaintextedit, qtextcursor

I have some text in QPlainTextEdit, where every line starts with 10 spaces:

```
          line1
          line2
          line3
          line4
```

Then, I select few lines and in a loop I want to remove first two spaces from all the selected lines:

```
cursor.beginEditBlock();
for (QTextBlock block = startBlock; block != endBlock; block = block.next()) {
    cursor.setPosition(block.position());
    cursor.setPosition(block.position() + 2, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
    cursor.removeSelectedText();
}
cursor.endEditBlock();
```

The problem is that the code above "damages" the last selected line - as if it removed some kind of end-of-line marker - when I want to jump to the end of last line the cursor moves to the line below it, between first and second character. Even the selection does not show up properly after the edit - all the lines but the last one have selection indicator expanded to the right window edge and the last line has the indicator only as wide as the line.

```
        line1    < 1. selected lines, run the code
        line2    <
        line3    <        < 2. here I jump to end of line
 |      line4

 ^ 3. cursor appears here
```

When I remove `beginEditBlock()` and `endEditBlock()` everything works fine.

Please, does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I think I might be running into the same problem in PyQt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320202/

Comment: @MichaelClerx IIRC it was fixed in 5.3.0, you can see the change [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/83583/).

Comment: Thanks! I've asked them to fix it in 4.8 too!

Answer (score 1):

With this condition `block != endBlock` your cursor will never reach the last block.
You should use this:

```
QTextBlock block = document->firstBlock();
while (block.isValid())
{
    // do your stuff
    block = block.next();
}
```

Comment: I posted the problematic code, above it there is basically something like `end = end.next()`. In any case, be it last or before-the-last line, the line somehow gets "corrupted".